# Method Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::resize does not exist using laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, intervention

I want to add a user (name, email, image, multiple images ...), and I tried to resize the image and multiple images for upload very quickly we use package intervention, I execute cmd `php composer require intervention/image`, i added `Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class` and `Image'=>Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class` in `config/app.php`, I also added `use Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException;` in `RegisterController.php` but still it gives me error `Method Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::resize does not exist`.

it gives me error `Method Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::resize does not exist`.

**RegisterController.php**

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
        'name'     => ['bail','required', 'string','min:3', 'max:50','regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u'],
        'email'    => ['bail','required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'telephone'=> ['bail','required','regex:/^06\d{8}$/','unique:users'],
        'password' => ['bail','required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'adressem' => ['bail','required', 'string', 'min:13','max:255'],
        'adressem' => ['bail','required', 'string', 'min:13','max:255'],
        'adresser' => ['bail','required', 'string', 'min:13','max:255'],
        'image'    => ['bail','required','mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,svg','max:2048'],
        'images.*' => ['bail','required','mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,svg','max:2048']
        ]);
    }
protected function create(array $data)
    { 
        //image
        $user = new User();
        //$jdate = Carbon::now();
        $request = app('request');
        if($request->hasFile('image'))
         {
        $image = $request->file('image'); 
         $url = Storage::put("user/" , $image->getClientOriginalName());
         $image->resize(250,125);
        
          $path = $request->image->store('profiles');
          $user->image = $path;
        }
        $im = $user->image;  
        //images
        $dataim = array();
         if($request->hasFile('images')) 
         {
            foreach($request->images as $file) 
            {   
                $file->resize(250,125);
                $path = $file->store('profiles'); 
                array_push($dataim,$path);
            } 
         }
        $user->images=json_encode($dataim);
        $imm =$user->images; 
        return User::create([
            'name'         => $data['name'],
            'email'        => $data['email'], 
            'password'     => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'telephone'    => $data['telephone'], 
            'country_id'   => $data['country_id'], 
            'state_id'     => $data['state_id'], 
            'autrei'       => $data['autrei'] ?? null, 
            'city_id'      => $data['city_id'], 
            'autreh'       => $data['autreh'] ?? null, 
            'adressem'     => $data['adressem'], 
            'adresser'     => $data['adresser'],
            'image'        => $im,
            'images'       => $imm
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow Package [DOC](https://github.com/Intervention/image).

First, Import the package

```
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
```

After that, Resize and save

```
$image = Image::make($filename);
$image->resize(250,125, function($constraint){
     $constraint->aspectRatio();
})->save($filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that your RegisterControlle has no errors.

Do you have install intervention/image for resize image?

with **composer require intervention/image**

add these also **use Image;**
in RegisterController

if Yes:
config/app.php

```
return [

    ......

    $provides => [

        ......

        ......,

        'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider'

    ],

    $aliases => [

        .....

        .....,

        'Image' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image'

    ]

]
```